After yarn link, locally started server crashes with the Failed to compile ../../email-editor/lib/cjs/email-editor.js:37:0 Module not found:
I have a repository named email-editor, and I'm trying to locally run my changes with email-editor in the designs project.
I'm using Windows OS and Git Bash as my terminal. When I run each repository separately locally, I don't encounter any issues. However, when I use yarn link to pull local changes from one repository into the other, I'm unable to start the server. It fails with the following error:
Failed to compile ../../email-editor/lib/cjs/email-editor.js:37:0 Module not found: Can't resolve '../node_modules/style-inject/dist/style-inject.es.js' 
What I Tried:
I followed a series of steps to integrate changes from the email-editor repository into the designs project:
Built the email-editor project using yarn build.
Navigated to the designs repository.
Used yarn link email-editor to create a symbolic link to the local email-editor package within designs.
Attempted to start the server in designs by running yarn qa.
Expected Outcome:
I expected the server in the designs project to start successfully after linking email-editor and applying its changes. Specifically, I anticipated that the changes from email-editor would seamlessly integrate into designs, allowing the server to run without issues.
Actual Result:
Unfortunately, the server startup (yarn qa) failed instead of starting successfully as expected. This outcome was unexpected and did not align with the anticipated result of a functional server running with the integrated changes from email-editor.
